# XSLT transformation based on odd and even

Tags: xslt

I want to convert below comma separated list to below output based on odd and even position through XSLT.

Input -

```
field1,value1,field2,value2,field3,value3
```

Output-

```
<root>
<field1>value1</field1>
<field2>value2</field2>
<field3>value3</field3>
</root>
```

Thanks in advance.

Regards
Nilay

Comment: Which XSLT processor respectively XSLT version do you use/can you use? It is solvable easily in XSLT 2.0 using `tokenize('field1,value1,field2,value2,field3,value3', ',')[position() mod 2 = 0]`.

Comment: XSLT 1.0 processor

Comment: Which XSLT 1.0 processor? Do you have support for http://exslt.org/str/functions/tokenize/index.html?

Comment: I am using XSLT in TIBCO. I think they have support for tokenize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a recursive template call without using extension functions...

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:param name="input" select="'field1,value1,field2,value2,field3,value3'"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
      <xsl:call-template name="process">
        <xsl:with-param name="toProcess" select="$input"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </root>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="process">
    <xsl:param name="toProcess"/>
    <xsl:variable name="name" select="normalize-space(substring-before($toProcess,','))"/>
    <xsl:variable name="value" select="normalize-space(substring-before(
      concat(substring-after($toProcess,','),',')
      ,','))"/>
    <xsl:variable name="remaining" select="substring-after(
      substring-after($toProcess,',')
      ,',')"/>
    <xsl:element name="{$name}">
      <xsl:value-of select="$value"/>
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:if test="string($remaining)">
      <xsl:call-template name="process">
        <xsl:with-param name="toProcess" select="$remaining"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output** (Using any well-formed XML input.)

```
<root>
   <field1>value1</field1>
   <field2>value2</field2>
   <field3>value3</field3>
</root>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.